# is the set measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space.

Let $f_n : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of measurable functions and $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. For every $\epsilon >0$ we define the set

$ A( \epsilon) =\{ x \mid f_n(x) - f(x) \mid < \epsilon\} $, $ \quad B(\epsilon)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf A_n (\epsilon) $.

I wish to prove that $B(\epsilon) \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $\epsilon >0$.

To do this I need to prove that $A(\epsilon) \in \mathcal{A}\quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ \forall \epsilon>0$ and this I gives me some difficulty because of the way the set is defined. Obviously I want to use that the functions that I have been given are measurable, but this gives me some issue.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define $g_n := f_n - f$. Then $g_n$ is measurable for every $n$ (why?) and $A_n(\epsilon) = g_n^{-1}((-\epsilon, \epsilon))$, i.e. $A_n(\epsilon)$ is the inverse image of an open set under a measurable map. This of course implies that $A_n(\epsilon)$ is measurable for every $n$ and $\epsilon$.

Notice that by definition we have $$B(\epsilon) = \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n(\epsilon) = \bigcup_{m}\bigcap_{n \ge m}A_n(\epsilon) \in \mathcal{A}.$$

This proves that $B(\epsilon)$ is measurable for every $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f_n$, $f$ are measurable, so is $f_n - f$.  It follows that $$A(\epsilon) = \{f_n - f > -\epsilon\} \cap \{f_n - f < \epsilon\}$$ is an intersection of two measurable sets.